# How can make div with a canvas inside it shrink when resizing a flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container (div) with two divs inside: one contains text, another one contains canvas.
When I reduce width of a flexbox first div shrinks but second div doesn't.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.textdiv {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.canvasDiv {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="textdiv">1111111111 123123123121</div>
    <div class="canvasDiv">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bairog/3p0sybk8/25/)

**UPDATE:** I want to have a Chart (Chart.js) inside my canvas (which shrinks when I reduce width of a flexbox) - it should look something like:

[image]
Howto solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: width:100% to canvas?

Comment: Adding `width: 90%;` to `.canvasDiv` gives an example of what you **might** want, but it's not really clear what you want.  The flex box shrinks because it it contains text which wraps.  Also note that scaling a canvas with CSS distorts whatever you draw inside.

Comment: I want to have a Chart (Chart.js) inside my canvas (which shrinks when I reduce width of a flexbox). **Width:100%** for canvas div solved my problem - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bairog/3p0sybk8/37/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because the canvas has `Width:auto` as Default value, The browser calculates the width of the canvas, to solve this you need to set max width or width 100% of their parent.

Comment: Thanks, was driving me nuts. Setting `max-width: 100%` on the canvas element, made it scale properly with its parent element.